# Inside docker, access container name

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have my docker-compose file. It works alright. At this point, I want to be able to access the container name inside the docker instances (like `master_app` or `slave_app_1`).

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    master_app:
        build:
            context: ./docker/app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: my-image/app
        ports:
            - "50000:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/laravel-app
        networks:
            - laranet-net
    slave_app_1:
        build:
            context: ./docker/app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: my-image/app
        ports:
            - "80"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/laravel-app
        networks:
            - lara-net
```

Inside docker, I have php (laravel) installed and using php's `getHostName()` I can get the Container ID.

```
NAME                     SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
lara-app_master_app_1    master_app          running             0.0.0.0:50000->80/tcp, :::50000->80/tcp
lara-app_slave_app_2_1   slave_app_2         running             0.0.0.0:51175->80/tcp
```

- Is there a way that I can get the container name: "master_app" / "slave_app_1"?

---

*The reason I need this is in order to load the right `.env` file for Laravel.*

One really poor way I tried was using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` but it won't work for CLI.

Comment: Would it be more flexible to add an environment variable to the container, something which indicates what role the container should work as.  Then you can change the names and the container will still operate properly.

Comment: @NigelRen How can I add environment variable so that I can access it within my container?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

Comment: It's always going to be easier to put a little extra info _into_ an abstraction like a container than it is to attempt to peek back outside of it.

Comment: @Sammitch Can you please expand on this?

Comment: It was intended in addition to Nigel's answer, but let's say you _did_ find a way to look at the container name in Docker. But then you change to Podman, or bare containerd, or run it in kubnernetes. You'd have to keep modifying your 'container name detection' to keep up. Feeding a little extra information in, eg: via an env var, maintains the abstraction and allows the container to operate independent of what/where/how the container is running.